# About the JavaWeb project server normal start, but not normal access to the project

Tags: tomcat, struts2, myeclipse

There is a small web program source code, there is no problem because in my classmates tested on the machine can run up, but my own environment Tomcat server running after the error can only access localhost8080 cannot access to the project page, display 404. also tried to compile the project manual posted to the webapps start, but still unable to access to the project. Then I've reconfigured the whole environment of the Myeclipse+tomcat. It's useless for several times, that is, myeclispe has been reloaded, and Tomcat has changed a few. So what could be the problem? Here is the server log after startup:  ``

```
  五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Server built: May 10 2017 15:02:19 UTC
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Server number: 7.0.78.0
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: OS Name: Windows 7
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: OS Version: 6.1
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Architecture: amd64
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Java Home: D:Javajdk1.8jre
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: JVM Version: 1.8.0_102-b14
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: CATALINA_BASE: D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: CATALINA_HOME: D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78/common/endorsed
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78temp
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Djava.library.path=D:Javajdk1.8bin;D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78bin
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
信息: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.12 using APR version 1.5.2.
五月 31, 2017 9:28:03 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
信息: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
五月 31, 2017 9:28:04 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
信息: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2k 26 Jan 2017)
五月 31, 2017 9:28:07 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
信息: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
五月 31, 2017 9:28:07 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
信息: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
五月 31, 2017 9:28:07 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
信息: Initialization processed in 6195 ms
五月 31, 2017 9:28:07 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
信息: Starting service Catalina
五月 31, 2017 9:28:07 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
信息: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
五月 31, 2017 9:28:07 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsdocs
五月 31, 2017 9:28:08 上午 org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
信息: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [765] milliseconds.
五月 31, 2017 9:28:08 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsdocs has finished in 1,310 ms
五月 31, 2017 9:28:08 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsexamples
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@29107c23')
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsexamples has finished in 781 ms
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappshost-manager
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappshost-manager has finished in 93 ms
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsmanager
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsmanager has finished in 78 ms
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsROOT
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsROOT has finished in 94 ms
五月 31, 2017 9:28:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsTax
五月 31, 2017 9:28:11 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
信息: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
五月 31, 2017 9:28:11 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
五月 31, 2017 9:28:14 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory D:apache-tomcat-7.0.78webappsTax has finished in 4,543 ms
五月 31, 2017 9:28:14 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
信息: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
五月 31, 2017 9:28:14 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
信息: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
五月 31, 2017 9:28:14 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
信息: Server startup in 7174 ms
```

Comment: It would be helpful if it was completely in English.

Comment: sorry,but I can make sure the tomcat server is OK

Comment: How do you access your project?

Comment: Thank you. I've solved my problem。

Answer (score 0):

Check the context root of your project. Right click on the project and select "Properties". Then, if using MyEclipse 2017, look at Project Facets->Web to find the Web context root. Or, if using MyEclipse 2013 up to 2016, look at MyEclipse->Project Facets->Web in the project properties. Make sure you access your project (assuming it was deployed properly) by entering http://localhost:8080  followed by the context root for the project. For example, if your context root is "my-app" then enter "http://localhost:8080/my-app". If this doesn't work, your project may not have been deployed and you will have to supply details of any errors during the deployment process.

Comment: Great! If my solution helped, please consider accepting it as the solution or upvoting it.